# magento 2 resource model "save" to implement service contract persistence operations. not saving POST empty

Tags: rest-api, resource-model, service-contract, repositories

I have a custom rest api for PUT and POST that the post data is an empty array therefore not saving as it's empty can anyone advise why or what could be wrong?

[image]

```
/**
     * Save data.
     *
     * @param RetailerImageInterface $retailerImage
     * @return RetailerImageInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function save(RetailerImageInterface $retailerImage)
    {
    /** @var RetailerImageInterface|\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $retailerImage */
        try {
            print_r($retailerImage->getData());
            $this->resource->save($retailerImage);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $retailerImage;
}
```

If I do `$this->request->getContent()` I can see post data but not through the repository save method.

Has anyone experience this It might be something silly that I'm missing but not sure what it is!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake in my model:

It looks like Magento set post array data individually with key pair value from the array to setData using setters even before I call any `print_r($retailerImage->getData());` method in repository save method.

setter methods had return of `getData` instead of `setData`.

All due to copy and paste! :(

Sorted!